# LiveValidation + UI TAbs - one page with multiple validations

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using LiveValidation of livevalidation.com for some simple and more complicated form validation on most of my projects.

Mostly to enhance user expirence.

What I did.
- replace invalid message from text to image
- when form is submited - and is not valid - focus on first not valid input field
- when form is submited - and is not valid - add red border to all not valid fields

What I'm trying to do:
- create function which be validating form - but for only on current tab

How can we do that 'manualy'
- We could create another var automaticOnSubmit2 = field4.form.onsubmit;

Where field4 is always first input on current tab. 
Because my tabs would be generated with unknown number of tabs - I'm looking for more universal solution.

I did some attempts - but my knowledge of js/jquery is very poor - so I failed.

//attempt 1

```
$(".ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide) > form")
```

- that is correct - firebug can found only 1 - open/current tab - where form which we wants to validate is located

  ```
  $(".ui-tabs-selected").ready(function() {
  var automaticOnSubmit = $(".ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide) > form").submit;
   $(".ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide) > form").submit = function(){
      var valid = automaticOnSubmit();
      if(valid)alert('Form is Valid!');
      else{ 
          $(".LV_invalid_field:first", document.forms).focus();
          }
      return false
  }
  ```

  });

Best Regards,

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Online demo 1](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17683975/multiple-form-one-page.html)**
**[Online demo 2](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17683975/multiple-form-on-tabs.html)**

**[Zip with both](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17683975/livevalidation.zip)**

Livevalidation + jQuery UI Tabs
Solution:

```
$("form").each(function (i) {
    var automaticOnSubmit = this.onsubmit;
    this.onsubmit = function(){
        var valid = automaticOnSubmit();
        if(valid)alert('Form is Valid!');
        else{ 
            $(".LV_invalid_field:first", document.getElementById(this.id)).focus();
        }
        return false
    }
});
```